# New ASP.NET Website and Redirecting All Old URL's

Tags: asp.net, .net, redirect, webforms

I have a website that will be completely redesigned. If I'd like to have users redirected to the new version of each page, is there a way to do that in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Example

old url - example.com/directory/staffdirectory.aspx
new url - example.com/directory-information/staff-directory/default.aspx

If a user types in the old url, I'd like them to be redirect to the new url. I'm going to be doing this for an entire website that has about 150 files that must be redirected and I have no admin access on the server (I develop locally and push to dev/prod). What are my options? Thank you.

Comment: Why is this being voted to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to web.config file then you can define each redirection rule from old page to new page as specified 
[here](http://www.victor-ratajczyk.com/post/2012/02/07/Webconfig-httpRedirect-Redirecting-individual-pages-with-301-302-and-307-status-codes.aspx) as an example.